# Button to call Application.OpenURL not working

Tags: unity, c#, android, unity-ui

I have a public method

```
public void patreononclick(){
   Application.OpenURL("http://www.patreon.com/HubakaGs");
}
```

This is supposed to open my Patreon page when a button is tapped.

But when I tap the button in the built application, nothing happens.

I have assigned the function to the On Click() section of the Button (Script).

I am building the game for Android and I use Unity 2017.1.0p4 Personal.

How can I make the button function properly?

Update:

I changed the function to

```
public void patreononclick(){
    Debug.Log ("the game should open patreon");
    Application.OpenURL("http://www.patreon.com/HubakaGs");
}
```

But when the button is clicked, there is no message in the console.

Comment: Have you properly set the internet access permission?

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Set "Internet Access" in the "Android PlayerSettings" window to "Require", see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html).

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 i did it and it still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

After hours of pulling hair, I finally noticed that this

[image]

was set to off, so I set it to Editor And Runtime, and it worked perfectly. I can even open the link from the editor trough a browser.

Comment: I changed it to Editor and Runtime, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are four things to check when your UI button click event is not firing…

1. Make sure your canvas has a `Graphics Raycaster` attached.
2. Your Image component's `Raycast Target` must be enabled.
3. Make sure there are no overlapping UI elements.
4. Make sure to have a gameobject with the `EventSystem` component in the scene.